# GDBus.Error:org.openobex.Error.Failed: No adapter found

Tags: bluetooth

hcitool scan is working fine but
bluetooth-sendto is giving error

GDBus.Error:org.openobex.Error.Failed: No adapter found

somebody help me

Comment: I'm having this issue too, on a fresh install of `13.04`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bug ([#1148033](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/1148033)) but I’ve found workarounds for this, described on the [comment #33](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/1148033/comments/33) and also on [Ubuntu Discourse](http://ubuntu-discourse.org/t/sending-to-bluetooth-device-workarounds/814). Try if it works for you.

So first, go to **System Settings** > **Bluetooth**, select the destination device and click on **Browse Files** instead of *Send Files*. The device will be mounted and then you will be able to copy-paste files.

If you have problems with *browsing files* as well, try to copy the device address, something like `00:25:E7:B1:53:3E`, from Bluetooth settings and enter in Files (Nautilus) as in:

```
obex://[00:25:E7:B1:53:3E]/
```

This should mount your bluetooth device either and then you can copy-paste files.

Comment: 'Browse Files' doesn't seem to be available in the Bluetooth settings menu on Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Comment: @yochannah I’ve already introduced a second workaround.

Comment: better answer (at least, more directly useful for Ubuntu 13.10 without having to click any links): http://askubuntu.com/questions/356692/gdbus-errororg-openobex-error-failed-unable-to-request-session-problem (no offense, @AliNa)