# GDbus.Error:org.openobex.Error.Failed: Unable to request session problem

Tags: bluetooth

This image & title explains all

[image: Error-screen "sending files via Bluetooth"]

Any way to solve this `GDbus.Error:org.openobex.Error.Failed: Unable to request session` error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It's a bug

There is a open [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/1148033) about this.

Apparently you can work around the problem installing and using blueman.

Answer (score 12):

If you run "bluez-simple-agent" (terminal or Alt + F2) you can send files.

Comment: It works. Now I wonder how to do it automatically

Comment: Add bluez-simple-agent to startup applications

Comment: You can add the line "bluez-simple-agent &" to ~/.config/openbox/autostart

Answer (score 1):

I received this error message too when trying to send files between laptop and phone, but it wasn't solved by using a different method of sending/receiving.

I could connect and 'pair' my device, however I couldn't send any files.
The problem was solved by finding and killing some other interfering processes. I can't explain why is worked, only present my solution.

I used "airmon-ng check" to find the processes, which I then killed:

```
:/#   airmon-ng check
Found 3 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
17689 NetworkManager
17694 wpa_supplicant
17696 dhclient
```

I then used the "kill" command for each of these in turn:

```
:/#  kill 17689
:/#  kill 17694
:/#  kill 17696
```

I did try to do it more methodically at first, only killing one at a time to check if I could then send a file, then two of them (working through all combinations) - however it only worked after all three were "killed".

I hope this helps somebody!!

Answer (score 0):

The receiving device may be "off". If needed,try to delete and add as "new" device. Make sure, you click the right device while transfer.